# Short Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My first try at a Riley Riddle, enjoy.

> My prefix fired bullets for King and Country,
>   My infix won't do what you say,
>   My suffix shows the relation of different quantities,
>   As a whole I will help you if you need to write fast.

Who/what am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you a

> Stenograph

This is a

> [fast typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenograph) for e.g. court reporters.

Explanation:

> Prefix: Sten, a [type of gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sten)
>  Infix: No
>  Suffix: Graph, referring to the [graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) (or maybe a line chart, charts are also sometimes called graphs)

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I'll have to think of something more difficult next time :)

Comment: @Edivad not at all, the difficulty level is just right in this one, it's just that Glorfindel is way too clever :-)

Comment: @Bass [s/clever/lucky/](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)